# Текст градиентом ie 11

Tags: html, css, css3

https://jsfiddle.net/4748o58L/

```css
.balance_title_subtitle_text {
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#52c1bf), to(#379c99));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #52c1bf 0%, #cc0000 10%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #52c1bf 0%, #cc0000 10%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #cc0000 10%);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class="balance_title_subtitle_text">ammed dit amed dollar</p>
```

как сделать, чтобы эти свойства css заработали в ie11?

Comment: это не возможно реализовать  так как  https://caniuse.com/#search=text-fill-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Единственное что мне пришло в голову это SVG и в IE11 только анимация не будет работать**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">

  <text x="50%" text-anchor="middle" y="50%" dy="0.4em" fill="url(#pattern)" font-family="sonos-logoregular" font-size="50vh">SONOS</text>
  
  <defs>  
    <!-- Da gradient -->
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#cc0000;"/>
      <stop offset="25%" style="stop-color:#dd22ff;"/>
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:#eedd99;"/>
      <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:#792042;"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#33235b;"/>
    </linearGradient>
    
    <!-- Stitch 2 gradients together for seamless animation  -->
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="300%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="150%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML"
                 attributeName="x"
                 from="0" to="150%"
                 dur="7s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </rect>
      <rect x="-150%" y="0" width="150%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeType="XML"
                 attributeName="x"
                 from="-150%" to="0"
                 dur="7s"
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </rect>
    </pattern> 
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**screenshot IE11**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://jsfiddle.net/sHaWW/359/ - пример в песочнице без анимации

Comment: Хорошее решение, правда много будет с этим проблем, особенно если текст на сайте формируется из handlebars, можно поставить когда на css который прочекает браузер  и отменит текст градиентом.
(-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active)

Answer (score 0):

Это имеется в виду?

```css
.balance_title_subtitle_text {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #379c99 100%); /* Standard syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #379c99 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #379c99 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #379c99 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */ 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #52c1bf 0%, #379c99 100%); /* IE 11 */
}
```

```html
<div class="balance_title_subtitle_text pick_balance_other">balance</div>
```

Или попробуйте генератор:
http://css3pie.com/

Comment: не работает в ie11

Comment: вы ж добавили код снизу в код стилей .balance_title_subtitle_text ?

Comment: я выполнил ваш код, в ie 11, текст черный на заднем плане градиент

Comment: изменил ответ, у меня работает

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn   у вас тоже не работает, не лукавьте

Comment: @МаксимЛенский http://prntscr.com/i197uu

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn у вас текст чёрный а должен быть градиентный - вы понимаете ? text-fill-color не поддерживается в ie11 что как раз вы и показали

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn я вопрос автора исправил  - посмотрите его в chrome или в лисе или в опере или в edge

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну вначале речь же шла про фон ) теперь понял